# Is there a formal definition for $f(x)$ ~ g(x)?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, definition

I was looking to see if curved asymptotes were possible and came across [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/850759/555796) that referred to an end behavior of a function as being $f(x)$ ~ $x^2$.  I'm assuming this either means the end behavior of a function or a generalization of what a function does given a set of large x values, but I don't want to simply assume something I don't know.  Is there a formal definition for what $f(x)$ ~ $g(x)$ is?

Comment: Yes. $$lim _{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=1$$

Comment: Sure is - $f(x) \sim g(x)$ as $x \to a$ if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)/g(x) =1 $. More generally, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation . $\sim$ is a refined version of $\Theta$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 So then it's just different notation, like f'(x) and d/dx?

Comment: @Phicar could you explain that a little more?

Comment: @jstowell with respect to $\Theta$? No, it's more than that. $f = \Theta(g)$ only demands that $f(x)/g(x) \to C$ for some constant $C$. $\sim$ demands that this constant is $1$. So for instance, $x/2 = \Theta(x)$ but $x/2 \not\sim x$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 that makes more sense, if you put it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I think $f=\Theta(g)$ does not require the limit $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)/g(x)$ to exist; only that the ratio is bounded between two constants.

Comment: I am surprised so many people upvoted the incorrect comment by @stochasticboy321.

Comment: @angryavian Right you are. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x) \sim g(x)$, I believe, is formally defined as $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$
Take $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2 - x$ for example. $f(x) \sim g(x)$ because $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x^2-x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x-1} = 1$$